# How to launch Flutter app from phone browser on Android and iOS by clicking a link?

Tags: flutter, dart, browser

I'm moving my user from my App to the browser to get payment.
After successfully finishing their payment in the browser(on my website) I want to show them a button to back to my app again. I did finish these steps.

Now I need to generate that link for html anchor tag which will redirect to my app by clicking the link (Like when we click on the Google map link it automatically redirects us to google map or shows a chooser dialog). I have seen some examples for Android-Java.
How can I do this in Flutter?

Comment: I was about to suggest Firebase Dynamic Links, but I just learned they are deprecated.  But this page lists some other options.  https://firebase.google.com/support/dynamic-links-faq

Comment: I want this link for my website.  Users will be their payment on the browser. I need to back to my app from the browser.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Deep Linking** in Flutter to enable navigation to specific screens or pages within your app based on URLs.

Please refer to the official [documentation](https://docs.flutter.dev/ui/navigation/deep-linking) about Deep Link.

Additionally you can use packages like [go_router](https://pub.dev/packages/go_router) to handle the inner routing in your app. It allows you to map URLs to specific page widgets and provides an easy way to handle navigation between different parts of your app.

Comment: I want this link for my website. Users will be their payment on the browser. I need to back to my app from the browser.